# Is it possible to determine if paper is stuck in printer via cups commands

Tags: printing, cups

When i check the current state of printer via `lpstat` command, cups returns `is ready and printing`. But printer doesn't print anything due to paper stuck.

Are there any ways to to check remotely if printer works properly or if paper is stuck. Also I couldn't find any logs regarding to cups errors. I've Canon Pixma ip100 Printer and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Query CUPS for the state of a printer-queue:

`#!/usr/bin/env ipptool -tv ipp://localhost/printers/my_pixma
{
  OPERATION Get-Printer-Attributes
  GROUP operation-attributes-tag
  ATTR charset attributes-charset utf-8
  ATTR language attributes-natural-language en
  ATTR uri printer-uri $uri
}`

This should output a lot of information. Look for printer-state attributes:

`printer-state (enum) = idle
 printer-state-message (textWithoutLanguage) = 
 printer-state-reasons (keyword) = none`

If the driver uses a fire and forget strategy CUPS is unable to detect malfuncions.